# How to set chart parameter in YouTube Data API v3( JAVA / Android)

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Hi here is my code to get videos list.

```
YouTube.Videos.List listVideosRequest = youtube.videos().list("snippet, contentDetails");
          listVideosRequest.setKey(apiKey);
```

I am not able to find a way to set chart parameter( one of the Filter option ). Actually i wanna retrieve videos list of Most popular in my region. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.
First check whether you included proper lib or not in your project. Because some times it may not show all methods. for updated library click [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/libraries).
Once you have updated library then

```
YouTube.Videos.List listVideosRequest = youtube.videos().list("snippet, contentDetails");
listVideosRequest.setChart("mostPopular");
listVideosRequest.setKey(apiKey);
```

Comment: Perfect... answer. Thank you. My problem was: i was not include updated library..